# What is SIGNED CURVATURE (Simple explanation)

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, frenet-frame

I know what curvature is; positive curvature, negative curvature, zero curvature, i understand.
BUT THEN.. Signed curvature? I just can't seem to find something that distinguishes enough difference between what I already know and what I'm trying to find out...

From what I am seeing online signed curvature is equal to curvature which is the norm/modulus/magnitude of the differential of tangent... so what is with the name..

Comment: Please give us the context. Are you talking about curves in the plane? Are you talking about curves on surfaces (in which case *normal curvature* is the *signed* curvature of a normal slice, the sign coming from whether the principal normal agrees with the surface normal or disagrees with it)?

Comment: I'm studying curvature in both

Answer (score 4):

If you understood what curvature is; positive curvature, negative curvature, zero curvature ....

THEN.. you innately understood what is signed curvature already.

By   *accepted conventions* if curving above tangent is positive, then drooping below it is negative... the tangential rotation is positive (counter-clockwise) or negative (clockwise).

EDIT1:

Any sign is an indication of how much is its departure from zero. Zero curvature is a property of a straight line. So look at: downward bend 1 blue , no bend 2 black and upward bend  3  red as three progressively bent states..somewhat like a debt situation which had at first got even and then later looked up by means of strong growth action, that is positive curvature addition.

With respect to x-axis reference, *Tangential rotation* in blue is clockwise, black nothing no change  and red anti-clockwise is positive.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A "static" circle of radius $R>0$ in the plane or in ${\mathbb R}^n$ has (unsigned) *curvature* ${1\over R}>0$. If, however, a circle, or any curve for that matter, in the plane is traversed in increasing time in a certain direction, and if  counterclockwise rotation is considered positive, then it makes sense to talk about *signed curvature* of this curve.

In this regard, let
$$\gamma:\qquad t\mapsto\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)$$
be a $C^2$ parametrization of $ \gamma$ with $\bigl(\dot x(t),\dot y(t)\bigr)\ne(0,0)$ for all $t$. Then
$$\theta(t):={\rm arg}\bigl(\dot x(t),\dot y(t)\bigr)\ ,$$
i.e., the polar angle mod $2\pi$ of the tangent vector of $\gamma$, is defined for all $t$. The quantity$$\kappa:= {d\theta\over ds}={\ddot y\dot x-\ddot x\dot y\over(\dot x^2+\dot y^2)^{3/2}}$$
is then the *signed curvature* of $\gamma$. This $\kappa$ is positive if the tangent vector turns counterclockwise with increasing $t$, and negative otherwise.