# Finding the signed curvature of $(t, t^3-3t)$.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, parametric, curvature

I'm looking to find the signed curvature of $(t, t^3-3t)$. Right now, I have evaluated the following:

The unit tangent vector is given by $\boldsymbol{T} =  \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{9t^4 - 18t^2 + 10}}, \dfrac{3t^2 - 3}{\sqrt{9t^4 - 18t^2 + 10}}\right)$

The unit normal vector is given by $\boldsymbol{N} = \left(-\dfrac{3t^2 - 3}{\sqrt{9t^4 - 18t^2 + 10}}, \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{9t^4 - 18t^2 + 10}}\right)$

But from here, it seems incredibly painful to continue working with these to find the signed curvature. Have I made a mistake? Is there an easier way to do this? What do I do from here?

Comment: $\kappa=\frac{\dot\gamma\cdot\dot\gamma\ddot\gamma-\dot\gamma\dot\gamma\cdot\ddot\gamma}{|\dot\gamma|^3}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use this formula:

$k=\frac{x'y''-x''y'}{(x'^2+y'^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$

[reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222870/what-is-signed-curvature-simple-explanation)